# Font problem - errors returned

Tags: fonts, ubuntu

I am using Ubuntu as OS. When I try to run a tex code, I receive this error from Textmaker :

```
! Font T1/ppl/m/n/12=pplr8t at 12.0pt not loadable: Metric (TFM) file not found
! Font T1/ppl/m/n/24.88=pplr8t at 24.88pt not loadable: Metric (TFM) file not found.
! Font \T1/ppl/b/n/24.88=nullfont not loadable: Metric (TFM) file not found.
...
```

It seems to be a Font problem, but I have no idea on how to fix it. Thank you in advance for your help. Please note that the same code could be run perfectly before. I tried to reinstall texmaker but it didn't helped.

**EDIT**
Please find on below the Packages used :

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage{ucs}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage{fancybox}
```

Comment: Welcome to tex.stackexchange! Is it it possible to edit your answer and add some code that illustrates your problem? Thank you!

Comment: Thank you for this warm welcome! Considering the code, I doubt that it will be useful, considering the errors given. However I will give you the packages I am loading.

Comment: @ Sigur: Thank you very much, it's solved now!

Answer (score 26, accepted):

As you tested, this solves the problem.

```
  sudo apt-get install texlive-fonts-recommended
  sudo apt-get install texlive-fonts-extra
```

Some expert could say if both packages are necessary or only one does the job.

Comment: I've verified that sudo apt-get install texlive-fonts-recommended Is sufficient to get ppl. I can't speak directly to your code though.

Comment: How to do that in Windows?

Comment: @SayOL, if you use MikTeX you can use its package manager.

Comment: @Sigur, I am using TeXLive "small scheme".

Comment: @SayOL so you can use tlmgr to install packages. Search for it on Google to know how to use.

Comment: See also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19688424/why-is-apt-get-function-not-working-in-terminal-on-mac-osx-10-9) if `sudo apt-get` is not working on a Mac terminal.